# Twitterscaper: Adding tweet country info to scraped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, twitter

I am using twitterscraper from https://github.com/taspinar/twitterscraper to **scrape** around 20k tweets created since 2018. Tweet locations are not readily extracted from the default setting. Nevertheless, the search for tweets written from a location can be done by using advanced queries placed within quotes, e.g. `"#hashtagofinterest near:US"`

Thus I am thinking to loop through a list of country codes (alpha-2) to filter the tweets from a country and add the info of the country to my search result. Initial attempts had been done on small samples for tweets in the past 10 days.

```
#set arguments
begin_date = dt.date(2020,4,1)
end_date = dt.date(2020,4,11)
lang = 'en'

#define queries
queries = [(f'(#hashtagA OR #hashtagB near:{country})', country) for country in alpha_2]

#initiate queries
dfs = []
for query, country in queries[:10]: #trying on first 10 countries
   temp = query_tweets(query, begindate = begin_date, enddate = end_date, lang=lang)
   temp = pd.DataFrame(t.__dict__ for t in temp)
   temp["country"] = [country]*len(temp)
   dfs.append((temp, country))
```

I managed to add country info as a new variable for each country df.
Part of output: [dfs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1gZf.png)
Part of output: [df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnM1T.png)

However, I am stuck at combining each query result into 1 dataframe. pd.concat() is not working for passing 22 columns on the passed data of 2 columns
[unintended result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXJs2.png)

My intended result is to have a new country column added to the default 21 columns in a dataframe (total 22 intended columns).
[intended result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iY3zH.png)

Comment: Since you’re breaking the Twitter Terms of Service and not using the official API, this doesn’t seem like a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `dfs` is a list of tuples, with each tuple being `(DataFrame, str)`, you only want to concatenate the first of each element of `dfs`.

You may achieve this using:

```
concat_df = pd.concat([df for df, _ in dfs], ignore_index=True)
```

which will create a new list of only the `DataFrame`s and concatenate those. I have added `ignore_index=True` so that the rows will be re-indexed in the concatenated `DataFrame`.

Since the `country` is already stored in the `DataFrame`, you could also not add this to `dfs` and only append `temp` instead:

```
dfs = []
for query, country in queries[:10]: #trying on first 10 countries
   temp = query_tweets(query, begindate = begin_date, enddate = end_date, lang=lang)
   temp = pd.DataFrame(t.__dict__ for t in temp)
   temp["country"] = [country]*len(temp)
   dfs.append(temp)

concat_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```